# How to detect the path in VUEJS to use v-show to condition in html?

Tags: vue.js, path, routes

I'm developing my first application in vue and I'm on the last page.
During all the application I used the same header and footer, but in this last page I want to replace the header with an image.
is it possible to get the path value to set a condition in the header component?
My intention was that in the component of the header I could use a v-show on condition that the coincidence of the path of this last page was fulfilled.

here´s my html

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <header>
                <div class="regular-header" v-show="regularPath">
                  <img class="logo d-lg-flex d-sm-none" src="../../assets/logoesthima.png">
                  <div class="logo-group d-lg-none d-sm-flex align-items-center">
                    <a href="https://www.testing.es/">
                    <img class="icon-logo" src="../../assets/logo.png">
                    <img class="text-logo" src="../../assets/text.jpg">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="final-header" v-show="!regularPath">
                   <img class="full-header" src="../../assets/finalheader.png>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
      </div>
</template>
```

and here´s my script

```
<script>

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      
      regularPath: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
      auth () {
        return this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated
      }
    },
  methods: {
    onLogout() {
      this.$store.dispatch('logout')
    }    
  }
}
</script>
```

If anyone can give me an idea of how to achieve my goal.
Thank you very much in advance for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `computed` property

```
<script>

export default {
  computed: {
      isRegularPath() {
        return this.$route.name === 'yourroutename'
      },
     
    },
  
}
</script>
```

Then just use it inside template

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <header>
                <div class="regular-header" v-if="isRegularPath">
                  code...
                </div>

                <div class="regular-header" v-else>
                  other code...
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
      </div>
</template>
```